# How to solve this diagram probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Question:

A system consist of 5 components in 2 branches.

The system work if component A and B works or if component C, D and E work. Assume that the components fail independenly with this probabilities:

P (A fails)= P (B fails)= 0.3     And.
 P (C fails)=P (D fails)=P (E fails)= 0.2

a) what is the probability the system works?
b) given the system works, what is the probability component A does not work?
c) given the system does not work, what is the probability component A also does not work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Just work out the tree diagram. My daughter, 16, could do it in a minute.

Comment: Just a quick check: when you write 'dependently' do you mean 'INdependently'?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Comparing other people with your smart daughter just isn't fair. My son, 16, has solved Riemann's hypothesis but he's too shy to deonstrate it.